# Can't get proper resultSet with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, many-to-many

I have 3 tables, Groupes, Assignements and Assignements_has_group which is doing the link between the previous ones (many to many relation). 
What I want to do is to get the idgroupes into the Assignement_has_groupes table to get the idAssignements and then be able to load the assignements thanks to their ID.

I have generated my classes and mapping from Hibernate and it hasn't created a class Assignements_has_group or hbm.xml file, but it's normal. 
My problem is when I am trying to access the table to get the data by doing

```
ArrayList<Integer> A = (Integer) session.createQuery("FROM Assignements_has_groupes WHERE Groupes_idGroupes="+"'"+id+"'").list();
```

I got an error saying that Assignements_has_groupes isn't mapped.

So I tried to access the table by native SQL but I can't get a proper Resultset, 
My code is :

```
ArrayList AS = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ResultSet AB= (ResultSet)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM assignements_has_table WHERE Groupes_idGroupes="+"'"+id+"'").list();
tx.commit();
int x=0;
while(AB.next()){
      int c =(int)AB.getInt(x); 
      AS.add(c);
      x++;
}
```

I don't achieve to get my resultset into an arrayList properly 
Which solution is the best and how do it ?

EDIT : 
hibernate config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


                <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->
<!--        <mapping class="com.isep.metier.entities.Competences2"/> -->

        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Users.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Absences.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Assignements.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Competences.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Competencesgrp.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Famillecompetences.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Famillecompetencesgrp.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Groupes.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Notes.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/isep/metier/Remarques.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What I want at the end is a ArrayList of int idAssignement to enable me to load assignements properly

For now the full stack error is :

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM assignements_has_groupes WHERE Groupes_idGroupes='1'
juin 22, 2016 12:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet GroupeEleve a généré une exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet
    at com.isep.metier.AssignementsUtil.AssignementByGrp(AssignementsUtil.java:48)
    at com.isep.controlleurs.GroupeEleve.doGet(GroupeEleve.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post your `entities`? and what is your expected result and what you are getting?

Comment: Can you please show your hibernate config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for handling any database relationship with Hibernate is letting it doing for you. This has to be specified in the mapping, tough. In Hibernate you can define two kinds of mappings: via xml or via Java annotations. For the next example I'll use annotations and at the end I'll leave two links with explanations of both methods and more examples.

In your specific case we are talking about a many-to-many relationship between two tables. This means that each element of the first table can contain more elements from the second table and viceversa. From a Java perspective, this is defined by a Collection. In this case I'll use a set.

```
public Assignment {

  // Your model.
  ...

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "Assignements_has_group ", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "ASSIGNMENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
  public Set<Group> groupes;

}
```

Basically, this will tell Hibernate that there's a many to many relationship mapped by table Assignements_has_group on columns ASSIGNMENT_ID and GROUP_ID. 
Also, you may want to set nullable = false and updatable = false if the relationship table doesn't contain null elements and you don't want to update the records of that table. You will have to do this for both the Assignment model and the Group model.

Once you've done that, to fetch your data you **won't** use the join table but the Groupes and Assignments tables. Here's an example of HQL query that fetches all the assignments for the group "testGroup":

```
String hql = "from Assignment a where :myGroup in elements(a.groupes)";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setString("myGroup", "testGroup")
.list();
```

**Disclaimer**

Notice that this code has been written on the fly and it's not tested, so it may contains bugs and may not work. This is just to give a roughly idea. If you have more problems, check the links below for a better tutorial on this.

**Source and more Examples**

Annotations: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

XML: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: what is the parameter "testGroup" representing ?

Comment: It represents a group you are looking assignments for. In fact, that query will return all elements that have been assigned to "testGroup".

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! :)